# RJDBC: get number of rows inserted

Tags: r, jdbc, rjdbc

How to get number of rows inserted or updated with RJDBC?
Example of such statement where I want get number of rows inserted:

```
conn <- RJDBC::JDBC(#params)
DBI::dbConnect(conn)
RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, "insert into mytable values(1)")
```

I'm using MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER. I have add it to my question :)

Comment: For inserts, you should use `dbSendUpdate`.

Comment: yee, my typo. I have edited.